# Any hints how to simplify $ \frac{\sin(a+b)}{\sin(a-b)} =\left(\frac{c-1}{c+1}\right)^2 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have this equation for three variables $a,b,c$, all reals

$$ \frac{\sin(a+b)}{\sin(a-b)} =\left(\frac{c-1}{c+1}\right)^2  $$

> I would like to rewrite (if possible) in the form

$$ f(a)=g(b,c) $$

I mean to obtain a simple relation for $a$ in terms of other variables. Any hints on how I can do this? or, is it possible to do that?

Comment: Expand $\sin(a+b)$ and $\sin(a-b)$ in terms of $\sin a, \sin b, \cos a, \cos b$, and then write this in terms of $\tan a$ and $\tan b$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $$\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\cos a \sin b\\\sin(a-b)=\sin a\cos b-\cos a \sin b$$
Then your equation becomes:
$$\frac{\sin a\cos b+\cos a \sin b}{\sin a\cos b-\cos a \sin b}=\left(\frac{c-1}{c+1}\right)^2$$
On the left, divide both numerator and denominator by $\cos a\sin b$. Remember to check the case when this is $0$.
$$\frac{\frac{\tan a}{\tan b}+1}{\frac{\tan a}{\tan b}-1}=\left(\frac{c-1}{c+1}\right)^2$$
It should be easy to find $\tan a$ from here.

Comment: @CalvinLin thanks for 1. If you find $\tan a/tan b$ as a function of $c$, just multiply everything by $\tan b$.